# After latest linux kernel 6.2 update monitor is black, does not recognize signal

Tags: 22.04, hdmi, monitor, linux-headers

My latest update:

```
2023-08-08 16:38:04 startup archives unpack
2023-08-08 16:38:04 upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.16 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:04 status half-configured ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:04 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:04 status half-installed ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:05 upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.16 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status half-configured ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status half-installed ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.10.2-1
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:05 upgrade python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.16 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status half-configured python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status unpacked python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status half-installed python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.16
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status unpacked python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:05 install linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 <none> 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status half-installed linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status unpacked linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:05 install linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 <none> 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:05 status half-installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:06 status unpacked linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:06 install linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 <none> 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:06 status half-installed linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:08 upgrade linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status half-configured linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status half-installed linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:08 upgrade linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status half-configured linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status half-installed linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:08 install linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all <none> 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:08 status half-installed linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:10 status unpacked linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:10 install linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 <none> 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:10 status half-installed linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 upgrade linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-installed linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 5.19.0.50.22
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:11 startup packages configure
2023-08-08 16:38:11 configure linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status installed linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26:all 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 configure python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.17 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status installed python3-distupgrade:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 configure ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.17 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status installed ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 configure linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status installed linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 configure ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.17 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status installed ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:22.04.17
2023-08-08 16:38:11 configure linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status unpacked linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:11 status half-configured linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:16 status installed linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:16 configure linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:16 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:16 status half-configured linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:16 status installed linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:16 configure linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:16 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:16 status half-configured linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status installed linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 configure linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status unpacked linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status half-configured linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status triggers-pending linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 configure linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status half-configured linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status installed linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:17 configure linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status half-configured linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status installed linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7
2023-08-08 16:38:17 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.10.2-1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.10.2-1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status installed man-db:amd64 2.10.2-1
2023-08-08 16:38:17 trigproc linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 <none>
2023-08-08 16:38:17 status half-configured linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
2023-08-08 16:38:30 status installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
```

has caused the monitor to stop working. Does not recognize signal.

How can I fix this?

```
inxi -Gx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics vendor: Dell driver: i915
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Dell driver: nouveau v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Creative Live! Cam Sync V3 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-3.3:6
  Device-4: Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-5:5
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```

```
sudo lshw -class display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f irq:184 memory:8b000000-8bffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:8c080000-8c0fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff irq:185 memory:6232000000-6232ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1440x1080     59.94  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.03  
   1280x960      60.09  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       60.00  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     60.06  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      60.07  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      60.06  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

```
sudo lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 24e0 (rev a1)
```

```
uname -a
Linux dell-g15 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is the screen not actually getting a signal, which would often lead to it turning off, or is there a small horizontal cursor line in the top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an external monitor that uses DisplayLink I don't believe kernel 6.x support displaylink without manual intervention.

https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?p=94837